# Error instalando apt-get install fcoe-utils en ubuntu server lts 16.04.1

Tags: ubuntu

```
# apt-get install fcoe-utils
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
fcoe-utils is already the newest version (1.0.29+git20140505-1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  libconfig9
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up dcbd (0.9.19-0ubuntu3) ...
insserv: Service network has to be enabled to start service dcbd
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package dcbd (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dcbd
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```